# Flickr API - Get the best photos by a tag or text or location

Tags: api, search, location, flickr, photos

I'm trying to get the best photos of different cities (places) using Flickr.photo.search, but I can't found the best way as always get some weird photos in results.

E.g. for https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=phuket&sort=interestingness-desc I see pretty photos but making e.g.

`https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&api_key=xxxxxxxxx&method=flickr.photos.search&sort=relevance&nojsoncallback=1&per_page=5&media=photos&extras=url_l,tags,machine_tags&place_id=Uvul4o1QULgHkGk8&min_date_taken=2015-01-01&min_date_upload=2015-01-01`

Gives me some photos I can't rely on. I was trying to use `sort=interestingness-desc`, using just `tags`, not using `place_id` and just using `text` and a lot of combinations. But in any case, I can't rely 100% on photos I get.

What data I have: City name, County name, coordinates. **I wish to get just 1-3 best photos of that city to show up.**

Of course, I need that in landscape orientation but can check that comparing height and width. 
To get all photo's sizes I don't see other ways except using 'flickr.photo.size'.

Is there a way to do that with 90% accuracy? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge recently, and I ended up searching like cityName + 'landscape' and with some validation it worked.